# Как записать событие в Cookie?

Tags: cookie

На странице при нажатии на `td` меняется рамка с помощью `onclick`:

```
<td class = "bordercolor" onclick = "this.className = (this.className == 'bordercolor-new')"><a href = 'силка'></a></td>
```

Подскажите, как `onclick` можно записать в куки, чтобы после перезагрузки `onclick` был уже как бы нажатым.

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну все же понятно - чтобы клетка выглядела нажатой после загрузки страницы, если оставалась нажатой во время ухода со страницы.

Comment: @Igor, теперь понял. Ответил.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/pvye7oxh/

В сниппете не работает из-за настроек безопасности.

```js
~function () {
  var elem = document.getElementById("dest")
  elem.className = document.cookie.match(/\bsmth=red\b/) ? 'red' : 'blue';
  elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.cookie = "smth=" + (elem.className === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red');
  })
}()
```

```css
.blue { color: blue }
.red { color: red }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="dest">
      Just some text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а что тильда тут означает `~function () .... `  не встречала такого еще?

Comment: @Elena, другой вариант форсировать expression вместо declaration. Просто самовызывающуюся функцию так написал. Можно `+` или `void` или любой другой унарный оператор.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: @Elena, но с плюсом плохо - он может неожиданно начать складывать :)