# Как записать событие в Cookie с атрибутом class?

Tags: cookie

[Здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/pvye7oxh/) запись куки по `getElementById`. Мне нужно, чтобы записывал `getElementsByClassName`. Пробовал ничего не получилось

Сильно не судите я только учусь.

https://jsfiddle.net/pvye7oxh/1/

Comment: Вот даже не знаю, голосовать за закрытие, или нет... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/640928/178988 В общем-то не дубликат и идейная разница по сравнению с тем есть, но отвечать лично мне уже не хочется... Может ещё кто ответит...

Comment: Везде, где указано get**Elements**By... - это живой массив. К элементам в нём нужно обращаться через цикл. https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/pvye7oxh/2/